# .Net MAUI (Android): System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInformationException: 'Success'

Tags: android, .net, couchbase, maui, couchbase-lite

I am experiencing the following error when my `Couchbase Replicator` starts:

```
System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInformationException: 'Success'
```

Firstly, this error does not make sense to me, then I stumbled upon this Pull-Request today:
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/78555

I have made sure to follow the guidelines as listed here:
https://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-lite/current/android/replication.html#lbl-cfg-tgt

After a few seconds, the application crashes and I am stuck with this error.

I recently upgraded to `.Net7`, and currently using an Android Emulator (Android 13 API 33), but previously on API level 31 this was never a problem.

Any idea what might be causing this issue?

Comment: Is this still an issue?  It looks like it was a bug in the .NET runtime regarding the retrieval of network addresses.

Answer (score 1):

The cause could be that currently Couchbase doesn't support API 33. Official support is only up to API 30 currently.

Comment: "we" refers to CouchBase?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Edited for clarity (I happen to know that "we" means Couchbase here)